# The article for detailed explanation of previous overall sentence.

Tags: grammar

In an article, I'm introducing some concepts to give details about them later. For example I have this sentence.

> We present our solutions in three groups; theory, implementation, and
>   execution models. In ??? theory group,

What is a correct article for `???` from `a',`the', or no article, and why? 
Or is it OK to use `the' with`first/second/third', i.e., `in the first theory group,`.

Comment: You might consider "We are presenting our...", though your version is not incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct article would be 'the', because you are referring to a single, particular concept that you have already introduced.  As a simple example:

> "I need *a* car"

Would mean that you need a car, but doesn't meant that you have a particular car in mind.

> "I need *the* car"

Is referring to a specific car.  In your case, I would write:

> We present our solutions in three groups: theory, implementation, and execution models. In the first group, theory, we find ...